# Loading 300 images on a custom spinner with images

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have a spinner that it has a custom layout with 5 imageviews and 1 textview. I would like to load it up with 80 rows, so it will display around 300 images (all images are within the app).

Is this a really bad idea?

All the images are loaded this way:

```
    class CustomAdapter : BaseAdapter
{
    private Context Context;
    private List<ButtonImagesTemplate> ButtonImagesTemplates;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<ButtonImagesTemplate> ButtonImagesTemplates)
    {
        this.Context = context;
        this.ButtonImagesTemplates = ButtonImagesTemplates;
    }

    public override Object GetItem(int position)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        if (inflater == null)
        {
            inflater = (LayoutInflater)Context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
        }

        if (convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.SpinnerTemplateModel, parent, false);
        }

        TextView nameTxt = convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.TemplateNameTextView);
        ImageView img1 = convertView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.TemplateImageView1);
        ImageView img2 = convertView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.TemplateImageView2);
        ImageView img3 = convertView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.TemplateImageView3);
        ImageView img4 = convertView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.TemplateImageView4);
        ImageView img5 = convertView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.TemplateImageView5);

        //BIND
        nameTxt.Text = ButtonImagesTemplates[position].Name;
        var drawable = AppCompatResources.GetDrawable(Context, ButtonImagesTemplates[position].Images[0]);
        img1.SetImageDrawable(drawable);
        img2.SetImageResource(ButtonImagesTemplates[position].Images[1]);
        img3.SetImageResource(ButtonImagesTemplates[position].Images[2]);
        img4.SetImageResource(ButtonImagesTemplates[position].Images[3]);
        img5.SetImageResource(ButtonImagesTemplates[position].Images[4]);

        return convertView;
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get { return ButtonImagesTemplates.Count; }
    }
}
```

also the layout here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="122sp">
    <LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50sp">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50sp"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:id="@+id/TemplateImageView1" />
        <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50sp"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:id="@+id/TemplateImageView2" />
        <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50sp"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:id="@+id/TemplateImageView3" />
        <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50sp"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:id="@+id/TemplateImageView4" />
        <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50sp"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:id="@+id/TemplateImageView5" />
</LinearLayout>
    <TextView
style="@style/MyTextStyle"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/TemplateNameTextView" />
<View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/LineHeight"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/LineMarginTopBottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/LineMarginTopBottom"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/ResourceOptionsMarginFromScreen"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/ResourceOptionsMarginFromScreen"
            android:background="@color/dark_grey"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have a list with all the Resource Ids, and all the images are vector .xml files. I tried to load the images with ffimageloading but as far as I am concerned XML are not supported. I added ffimageloading.svg nubegt package and do some tests and the image was not displayed.

So what I would like to ask: is this a bad idea? Should I find a library to load the images like ffimageloading or picasso? If yes, which one?

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview! Thanks for taking the time to post your code and question. CodeReview is meant for you to post complete, functioning, code for review by other members. Snippets and code that doesn't work as intended aren't reviewable, as we can't look at overall design patterns, etc. Your question is better suited for StackOverflow.

Comment: i have put the complete code of my custom adapter of the spinner that works, is it still not suitable here? if yes why? its a full functioning code that i want to improve

Answer (score 1):

If do you need load big count image i recommend you using libraries for working with images. Example : glide , picasso. Otherwise, you will experience performance problems.
Example code for gllide :

```
 Glide.With(context)
.Load(R.drawable.resource_id)
.Into(imageView);
```

Also here you get the values ​​from the array, but you did not check if the number of values ​​in the array

```
    img2.SetImageResource(ButtonImagesTemplates[position].Images[1]);
    img3.SetImageResource(ButtonImagesTemplates[position].Images[2]);
    img4.SetImageResource(ButtonImagesTemplates[position].Images[3]);
    img5.SetImageResource(ButtonImagesTemplates[position].Images[4]);
```

Here you can see additional information : https://bumptech.github.io/glide/

Comment: i have try glide and i cannot install it, it is 3 years old the latest update in xamarin, and it has incompatibility issues.
I have also try picasso and FFImageLoading and they don't support vector .xml images

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35508121 , take a look maybe it will help

Comment: If nothing succeeds and there are no problems loading so many images, leave it as it is.